# SSRS Updating Report when Dataset Query changes

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which draws from dataset X. I have updated the query in dataset X by limiting the date from no restriction to past 24 hours.

Now that the dataset has changed, how do I make sure the data within the report is also up to date- i do not want to recreate the report as it had a lot of formatting that i did.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just run the report it will query the changed ataset and provide data accordingly.  U

Comment: it did not change it that's what is confusing. It is a shared dataset

Comment: If your using BIDS or SSDT then delete the .data file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Basically you have to clear cache

Below link is very useful

http://jasonfaulkner.com/ClearDataCacheBIS.aspx